# ANDROID can get selected item string

Tags: android, listview

I've got problem with my listview adapter.

Please check my code below:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selected;

    selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    if( selected == "Apple" ){
        Intent apple = new Intent(Fruits.this, Apples.class);
        startActivity(apple);
    }
    else if( selected == "Apricot" ){
        Intent apricot = new Intent(Fruits.this, Apricots.class);
        startActivity(apricot);
    }
    else if( selected == "Avocado" ){
        Intent avocado = new Intent(Fruits.this, Avocado.class);
        startActivity(avocado);
    }

} // end of OnItemClick method
```

Whenever I select a row, it's throwing a nullpointerexception on this line:

```
        selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

What is the problem here? please help. thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you should check if parent is null or if getItemAtPosition returns null. And a full stack trace is recommended.

Comment: @WarrenFaith so I should include selected == null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your excpetion use the following code,

```
selected = parent.getItem(position).toString();
```

Also you have used,

```
if( selected == "Apple" ){
```

Its not correct way to compare strings, Instead of it use,

```
if( selected.equals("Apple") ){
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should write

```
 if( selected.equals("Apple")){
//Do your Code
}
```

instead of

```
 if( selected == "Apple" ){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + position).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing `equality` of string ,We Use equals() Method. There are two ways of comparison in Android.

One is "==" operator and another "equals()" method .

`"=="` compares the reference value of string object whereas `equals()` method compares content of the string object. .

use

```
selected.equals("your string")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
    tv.getText().toString(); // String
}
```

You can get child view of your list item like the above way.

Answer (score 0):

If your adapter contain model, use this code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        itemDrawer seleted = (itemDrawer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), seleted.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```